# php PDO vs. Custom DB Class

Tags: php, pdo

I am wondering the merits of using a PDO verses creating your own custom database class and vice-versa. Yes the PDO is already developed and documented, but PDO can change or go away due to no action of yours. Whereas your custom database class needs to be developed and no only the documentation you give it, but the only change it will undergo are the ones you make. I would be interested in knowing the thoughts of someone who is more knowledgeable on these subjects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"but PDO can change or go away due to no action of yours" That logic can be applied to PHP as a whole as well.

I wouldn't spend the time creating my own. It's already made for you, documented and ready to go. When/if the time comes to change it, worry about it then. But, in all honesty, as I said before, any function or class in PHP could go away as well.

Comment: +1 documented. which is very important!

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is, why reinvent the wheel? PDO comes out of the box with a lot of features, such as prepared statements; it's nicely object oriented, database agnostic etc. Furthermore, it's the recommended database library to use, so I doubt very much it's going to go away unless PHP goes with it. Plus it's a core extension (written in C) so it's going to be a lot faster than anything home rolled in PHP, no matter how well it's done

In summary: it's not going away, and it's pretty good. Use it :)